# Javascript bold string from word to period

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Say I have this string:

> This has happened at it's outrageous! A big tornado might be coming
>   towards you. But I'm not certain!

How can I through Javascript or Jquery make a portion of it bold, so that it becomes this:

> This has happened at it's outrageous! A big **tornado might be coming
>   towards you.** But I'm not certain!

A `<b>` is added before "tornado" and a `</b>` is added after the first period that comes after tornado.

So that the rule is: "Find the word tornado, add a `<b>` before it and add `</b>` after the first period that comes after the word tornado"

Would appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example below uses a regular expression and basic DOM operations to achieve what you've described.

```js
function highlightFromWordToPeriod(words) {
  let el = document.querySelector('.my-text');
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(`((${words.join('|')})[^.]*.)`, 'g'), "<b>$&</b>");
}
```

```html
<div class="my-text">This has happened at it's outrageous! A big tornado might be coming towards you. But I'm not certain! Watch out for hurricane as well.
</div>
<p>
  <button onclick="highlightFromWordToPeriod(['tornado', 'hurricane'])">Replace</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about the $& in replace.

Comment: Can I somehow have several words such as tornado? Say that the entire string varies between "tornado" and "hurricane", can i somehow include both of these words?

Comment: Updated the answer to match several words. Pass array of words to `highlightFromWordToPeriod` function.

Answer (score 0):

First select the part of the sentence that you want to bold using Regular Expression. Then simply replace using string replace method.

```
var str = "This has happened at it's outrageous! A big tornado might be coming towards you. But I'm not certain!";
var matchRes = str.match(/tornado[\w\s\W]*\./);
str = str.replace(matchRes[0], "<b>"+matchRes[0]+"</b>");

console.log(str);
// This has happened at it's outrageous! A big <b>tornado might be coming towards you.</b> But I'm not certain!
```